# Intercepting keyevents to MediaController?

Tags: android, mediacontroller

Basically, I'm trying to recreate the functionality of the MediaController in the native Music app (that I see on 2.2), where the back button immediately backs out of screen, instead of hiding the MediaController. There doesn't seem to be any good way to set a keylistener or override a method to intercept these keyevents though.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like

```
mMediaController = new MediaController(this) {

        @Override
        public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                finish();

            }
            return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
        }
}
```

or the dispatchKeyEvent like

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    ContentActivity.this.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: The dispatchKeyEvent is being invoked twice for single backpress any idea why?

Comment: @Jasper, because it reacts first on ACTION_DOWN and then on ACTION_UP. If you want to handle it only once, use `event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP`